# Where are string objects when created using tostring methods stored in memory in Java?

Tags: java, string

I was doing one assignment, and I got this following question.

Where are the string objects created with the `toString()` method stored in memory?

```
String a = Integer.toString(10);
```

1. In the constant pool
2. On the heap (the area of new operator object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was an odd (I would say poor) interview question you were asked, because the answer to this question depends on the JDK's implementation. This implementation can change, and is not something a normal person would be expected to know about, because to find out for sure, you need to ask the implementers or read their source code. Also, as of Java 7, the string pool (which is what I'm assuming is meant by "constant pool") is on the heap. So even if it's in the string pool, it's still on the heap.

Currently ([OpenJDK 8u40-b25](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28int%29)), that `String` will be a new object created in heap memory:

```
public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```

Because you're passing `10`, not `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, a new `String` object is created. The contents of this string are a `char` array that was created with `new`, so exists on the heap. `intern()` is not called on it, so it isn't put into the string pool.

---

You can test that this is the behavior you're getting by using the fact that `==` with `String`s tests if they're the same object, not the same value. The following will evaluate to `False`, because the static `Integer.toString()` method created a new `String` object on the heap each time it was called:

```
Integer.toString(10) == Integer.toString(10)
```

If they had been interned into the string pool, they would be the same object (because that's the point of interning—having only one object per string). The following evaluates to `True`:

```
Integer.toString(10).intern() == Integer.toString(10).intern()
```

---

Note that this is an answer specifically for the static `Integer.toString()` method, not for all `toString()` methods. `Boolean.toString()`, for example, returns strings from the string pool.

Comment: Hi Dan, sorry if the quetion was not asked properly.. but I do intend to say that both are on heap ... your to string thery suggests that internally for tostring method of integer, the string object is created like a new operator, so by default no intern is called... so can i conclude saying that if    string a = Integer.toString(1) is kept in a loop of 10 then 10 different string objects are created...

Comment: Hi Dan, sorry if the quetion was not asked properly.. but I do intend to say that both are on heap ... your to string thery suggests that internally for tostring method of integer, the string object is created like a new operator, so by default no intern is called... so can i conclude saying that if    string a = Integer.toString(1) is kept in a loop of 10 then 10 different string objects are created...

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of it. I didn't mean to criticize your question. It's an interesting question. I was criticizing that this was a question on an assignment you received, because this isn't something that someone using or studying Java should be expected to know.

Comment: With assignment I didnt mean college assignments.. I am a java professional... This is one of the interview questions i was asked(I collected a series of questions asked to me in almost 10 interviews and started to solve them... only to know there is lot to learn)... I ended up saying that only one object is garbage collected...

Comment: Exactly, what I meant to say, then, was that I think this is a bad question for an interview, for the reasons I gave in my answer. @Boann 's answer goes into more detail about that.

Answer (score 24):

They all go into the *heap memory*. Only *String literals* and *interned* strings go into the String constants pool.

The only exceptions are classes like `String`:

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

It just returns the current string (if it is on heap, it returns from the heap / if it is on string constants pool, it returns from the string constants pool)

Note : If `toString()` is NOT overridden to return a *String Literal* explicitly, the String representation (ClassName@hexValueOfHashCode) is *always* created on the heap.

Comment: Also e.g. `Boolean` returns a literal.

Comment: This is about instance `toString()` methods, not the static method `Integer.toString()`. Or do you mean it applies to both?

Comment: @DanGetz - In a general way... `toString()` is not guaranteed to intern strings and return them..

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the implementation of the `toString()` method that you are calling.

The `toString()` method creates the `String` object, so depending on how it does this (and whether it interns the string or not), the returned `String` will be in the string pool or not.

Note that `toString()` is just a method like any other method. There is no magic that handles the return value of the `toString()` method in any special way. (Strings returned by `toString()` are, for example, not interned automatically). It works in exactly the same way as with any other method that returns a `String`.

Comment: hi jesper, I understand your point of tostring method. My question here is related to Integer's class to string method... The code snippet is as follows:for(int i=10;i>=0;i--){

 String a = Integer.toString(1);

 System.out.println(tmp);

 } and I have to find out how many string objects are available for garbage collection.. when the code is out of reach.. i.e outside of loop

Answer (score 3):

The question you were given is flawed.

First of all, the two options: (1) returning a string that's in the constant pool, and (2) returning a newly created string, are not mutually exclusive, because a method could create a new string, but then [`intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) it to get it into the constant pool.

Secondly, there are *no* particular requirements for how `toString()` methods go about supplying their strings in general. It's entirely up to the particular implementation of the particular `toString()` method. You can't generalize and say they all do a certain thing.

- Some methods may return a `new String(...)` on every call (which would suitable for say, a `StringBuilder`).
- Some methods may always return a string instance from a small set of fixed possibilities, and these fixed possibilities *might* also be in the constant pool (which is suitable for class `Boolean` or for enum constants).
- Some methods may do a mix of things. `Integer.toString(int)` might use a set of predefined constants for small common values, but return new heap strings for more obscure values. Or it might generate and cache strings on demand, so that `Integer.toString(10)` could return a new heap string the first time, but return the *same* heap string on subsequent calls; and in that case, if a caller of `Integer.toString` somewhere `.intern()`s its return values, then the `Integer` class's on-demand-cached instances could thus also get into the constant pool.

The behavior could also vary depending on the JVM flavor or JVM version or runtime options that are passed to it.

To the specific question of what `Integer.toString(int)` currently does in OpenJDK 8, [check the source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java):

```
public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```

It turns out it returns a string literal (which will be in the constant pool) for `Integer.MIN_VALUE` but a new heap string for every other value. (It may look odd but it is common for number-to-string functions in many programming languages to make an exception for the min value in this way, because with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of integers the max value is 1 less than the absolute of the min value (e.g., range of -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647) which means the min value is the only negative value you can't flip to positive and then process using the same shared loop code as for the positive values.)

The third problem with the question is that the answer would *hardly ever matter*. Only if you find the implementation of a `toString()` method is not working or has unsatisfactory performance, then you can investigate why, but otherwise, so long as it works, and works efficiently, why should anyone care how it caches strings or whether it caches them or not? Java newbies are made to worry far too much about the details of the silly string constant pool, which is an unfortunate side-effect of Java's poor decision to not have `==` call `.equals()` for objects, which makes the behavior of the constant pool more noticeable.

When you need a string that's definitely in the constant pool, you can intern it yourself, or write it as a string literal in the source. Otherwise, you have no guarantee whether it is or isn't in the constant pool, but also don't need such a guarantee.

Based on the implementation of `Integer.toString(int)`, they are probably looking for the answer **2** ("on the heap") but it is a flawed answer to a highly flawed question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it should depend on implementation. But for default toString from `java.lang.Object` and many other objects' `toString` implementations return only string literals. So I can tell you that they are in string constant pool because by default they are `interned` and all interned strings will be stored in string constant pool.

**Example 1**

```
public String toString() {
   return "my test string";  // will be in string constant pool
}
```

**Example 2**

```
public String toString() {
   String s1 = new String("my test string");
   return s1;  // s1 will be in heap
}
```

Of course I do not have to have to tell you that `s1.intern()` will put the example string in string constant pool if that is not already available

Comment: Object's `toString()` is not *interned*. Why should `toString()` return only literals?.

Comment: Clearly wrong that `Object.toString()` returns a literal. Try `new Object().toString()` and you'll see.

Comment: How do you say that object.toString() does not return literal ?? Object o = new Object();String s1 = o.toString();String s2 = s1.intern();System.out.println(s1 == s2); This returns true. What do you it means?

Comment: how do you get that ? I am sorry to ask though. However the answer that interned strings are part of constant pool is right anyways.

Comment: @DanGetz Even if `s == s.intern()`, it doesn't necessarily mean that `s` was already interned before the call to `intern()`.

Comment: @sakthisundar actually the result of `toString()` **isn't** interned. What you did was intern it yourself, *then* test if it was interned. You can test that it truly isn't interned with the following code: `String s = new Object().toString(); System.out.println(new String(s).intern() == s)`. This prints `false`, which means that the result of `toString()` is not what was put in the string pool.

Comment: I deleted my mistaken comment above, so I'll repost here that you're using the word "literal" incorrectly: a "string literal" is "a string that's written in source code", *not* "a string that's interned". String literals are interned, but not all interned strings are literals.

Comment: @DanGetz : what are the other strings that are interned other than literals.

Comment: @PrakrutiPathik you can intern any string you like by calling [`.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) on it.

Answer (score 1):

In the Integer wrapper class, once the given int is parsed to char it will return a new String object.

```
return new String(buf, true);
```

this will create 1 string object in Heap Memory.

The reference variable "a" will point to the object in heap(normal memory).

But be remember that,

```
String str = new String("abc");
```

will create 2 objects, one in heap and other in String pool.

> Compile time Constants Expressions of type String are always interned.

Answer (score 0):

It's **implementation dependent**. However by default the string go to the string pool.

Case 1:

```
public String toString() {
   return "Constant Pool";  // String constant pool
}
```

Case 2:

```
public String toString() {
   String string2 = new String("Heap String");
   return string2;  // in heap
}
```

Both expression gives you `String` object, but there is subtle difference between them.

- When you create `String` using `new()` operator, it always creates a new object in **heap** **memory**.
- If you create object using String literal syntax, it may return an existing object from **String pool** if it's already exists. Otherwise it will create a new string object and put in string pool for future re-use.

> When you create string using **String literal** notation, it automatically call `intern()` method to put that object into **String pool**(if it wasn't in the pool already). In case of new, it doesn't take place automatically, until `intern()` method is called on that object.

Comment: Neither example is related to the question, which was about the static method `Integer.toString()`.

Comment: Why @DanGetz? The answerer touch the exact point of the implementation dependency and how it relates to the specific implementation.